# Using if else conditional operator in asp.net razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net5

In asp.net5 razor pages application I have the following piece of code which is working

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsComplete)
```

It shows a disabled checkbox as IsComplete is a boolean.

I would rather like to have a text in place of the check box and so I tried the two below unsuccessfully..

```
@Html.Raw(modelItem => item.IsComplete == true ? "Completed":"")
```

and

```
@(modelItem => item.IsComplete == true ? "Completed":"")
```

The error I get is error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrapped with @if()

```
@if(Model.isCompleted) {
<p> Completed Transcation </p>
}
```